# Creating a component by overriding BlazorComponent.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I am learning Blazor.
https://learn-blazor.com/

I am having some difficulty creating a component in C# by overriding the `BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)` method of the `BlazorComponent` class.

Here is my class:

```
   public class TestComponent : BlazorComponent
    {
        protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.OpenElement(1, "p");
            builder.OpenElement(2, "strong");
            builder.AddContent(3, "hello");
            builder.CloseElement();
            builder.CloseElement();

            base.BuildRenderTree(builder); // With or without this line it doesn't work
        }
    }
```

I use it in my page like this:

```
<TestComponent></TestComponent>
```

I have tested it with and without that last line `base.BuildRenderTree(builder);` but either way it doesn't render. I've made the component childishly simple (just a paragraph tag, strong tag and one word of content) so I'm lost as to why it won't render. The code builds just fine.

Can anybody see what I did wrong please?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you trying to build your blazor component in this way rather than doing it idiomatically through your `.cshtml` file?

Comment: Partly just to learn how as it will always come in handy in some scenario.

Comment: And partly so that I can begin creating a library of reusable Blazor components for my future projects. Once I get this simple example working, I hope to create more complex ones that use RenderFragment properties, allowing me or other developers to specify their own HTML that can be rendered as part of the control.

Comment: +1 on just learning how to do things and how things work.  But that said, I don't think this approach is required for creating reusable components using render fragments.  I've written several components in my projects where the component was entirely defined via `.cshtml` but populate its contents via `RenderFragment` properties.  IMO, this approach is way easier to work with, which is the reason for my question.

Comment: I'm working towards something like an UsernameValidator component that is based on an AsyncValidator abstract component, that might be used something like this:

<UsernameValidator ControlToValidate="email">
<PendingContent><img src="loader.png />Checking your username hasn't already been registered...</PendingContent>
<InvalidContent>Oh no! That name is registered. Pick another, or did you mean to <a>log in</a>?</InvalidContent>
<ValidContent>Perfect!</ValidContent>
<UsernameValidator>

Comment: I'm using Blazor 0.7.0 and code you posted works just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off don't use that web site anymore. I've learned Blazor through that web site. It is an excellent web site, and the guy did a superb work. But alas, he stopped updating it, at least for the last six months. The materials have become old and useless. Right now, I'm not aware of any good substitution.

Try this:

1. Place `base.BuildRenderTree(builder);` at the start of the BuildRenderTree method , not at the end.
2. Use `ComponentBase` instead of `BlazorComponent`... 
   BlazorComponent is dead...
3. Always start with the value `0` for the sequence parameter.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the fast response and good advice! It's easy when you know how, huh? So I've moved the base.BuilderRenderTree(builder) call to the beginning of the subroutine. But what about this ComponentBase class you say I should inherit? I couldn't find it in the source code on GitHub. In what assembly and namespace will I find ComponentBase, please?

Comment: See this: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Components

Comment: +1 for information about BlazorComponent death. Unfortunately, couldn't find anything on tutorial sites about this

Comment: &qki, at the beginning the base class of the component object was called  BlazorComponent ... As time elapsed it was changed from BlazorComponent to ComponentBase, just as UriHelper has changed to NavigationManager. Many objects in Blazor has undergo name changes and more as the framework has been created... Of course no tutorial is going to tell you that. Tutorials are about the current state of the framework, not about the history of the framework development.