# Add components based on string variables in Blazor

Tags: razor, blazor

We're creating a dynamic page of components in Blazor. The intention is to have dynamic applets displayed on a page. The idea is that we have a list of strings which correspond to Component names. We read through the string list and for each one, instantiate a blazor component or render fragment. These are just simple components, no passed in parameters or the like. ie:

`string[] componentsStrings = {"Component1", "Component2"};`

Expected output:

```
<Component1 />
<Component2 />
```

We can't come up with a way to do this. It seems like a fairly standard thing to do, but perhaps not? Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to programmatically create a component which adds your custom components on the page using RenderTreeBuilder.

Chris Sainty has a blog post on this which you can read here: https://chrissainty.com/building-components-via-rendertreebuilder/

Basically there is an override for `BuildRenderTree` in the `ComponentBase` class which can be used:

```
public class Menu : ComponentBase
{
    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
        builder.OpenElement(0, "nav");
        builder.AddAttribute(1, "class", "menu");
    }
}
```

Here is another [tutorial](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2019/07/19/how-to-dynamically-build.aspx).

Some tips from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53582845/1158845):

- Place `base.BuildRenderTree(builder);` at the start of the
  `BuildRenderTree` method , not at the end.
- Always start with the value `0` for the sequence parameter.

Comment: The `0` clause isn't required. They are actually keys rather than a sequence, you can put any value in there you like as long as it is unique within its parent.

Comment: Thank you for that. I've just tried this approach with partial success. 

This approach allows us to add classes if we know what they are (ie if (name == "TestComponent") but doesn't use the string itself.

We have dynamically loaded components. The plan was to be able to add more at a later date without having to edit the code to add in 'if (name=="NewComponent")'.